# Why does the US keep announcing what they think Russia is going to do in Ukraine?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, ukraine, foreign-policy, propaganda

There must be some motive here that I can't understand. For one I can easily think of reasons why the US wouldn't want to make public the things that they know, if not for any other reason than to risk revealing how they know what they know. Other than that sometimes it's better to not let the "adversary" (for lack of a better term) know that you know the cards they are holding.

On the other hand I can think of reasons why you wouldn't want to keep making these kinds of announcements, like freaking out people in Ukraine. Wouldn't it be better to just tell the Ukrainian government what you know and let them decide how to handle the public relations in the matter?

It just seems very surreal, if you watch the mainstream news or listen to the President or other officials making statements they claim to know these very specific details but I can't figure out why we are hearing it from the US and no other source, or why we are hearing it from the US at all.

This seems like a multi-faceted question but really it comes down to why is the US specifically pumping out all these statements and claims about Russia/Ukraine in the first place? What could the possible motive be for the US?

Comment: Consider the value of keeping the populace informed.  Given a choice between being upset ('freaked out') by knowing that an invasion was coming, allowing me and my family to plan for our safety, to fight or to flee, vs. being kept ignorant, I'll take the former.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This is fairly common political technique called 'poisoning the well'. The US is laying out all of the actions and steps that Russia has been taking — and some that they expect Russia will take if there *is* an invasion — thus making it extremely difficult for Russia to claim *after the fact* that an invasion was necessary as a response or reaction to something that occurred within Ukraine.

Putin has been carefully trying to craft a narrative that Russian-speaking peoples in eastern Ukraine are under some sort of existential threat, but knows that staging a bald-faced invasion would violate a number of international treaties and norms. It would be best for him politically if there were an international incident that would justify sending troops across the border (much as 9/11 became a justification for the US invasion of Afghanistan, albeit under shady logic). By carefully spelling out all of Russia's preparations and troop mobilizations, the US is undercutting Putin's 'justified response' narrative, effectively saying: "Why would Russia prepare so extensively for an as-yet-to-occur international incident?".  Note that in the US invasion of Afghanistan, all of the preparations and mobilizations began *after* the trigger incident, and the US was quite public about its intentions, seeking international agreement and support. Russia, by contrast, has played its cards close to its chest: massing its forces without much comment, creating public misdirections about non-existent troop withdrawals, ginning up the *potential* of a genocide where no overt evidence of genocide exists.

Russia wants uncertainty and confusion over the nature of its actions, so that it can spin out *ex post facto* rationales and maintain some semblance of its international reputation. The US is doing its best to remove any uncertainty or confusion, so that any actual invasion will merely look like naked aggression on Russia's part.

Comment: 'poisoning the well' wins it, such a common tactic in politics everywhere (go wave a nazi flag at any event you don't agree with for example) was a tough choice otherwise but I also thought this answer felt generally more neutral

Comment: "Putin has been carefully trying to craft a narrative..."  For comparison, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Himmler, Germany's propaganda attempting to justify the invasion of Poland in WWII.

Answer (score 149):

I think that the motivation is mostly to make it very hard for any Russian narrative to gain traction in the international public opinion, including in Russia.

From a political perspective, Russia needs a good reason to invade Ukraine, otherwise it will look as the clear aggressor to everybody. Without a [casus belli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_belli), Russia would become a [rogue state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_state), lose its legitimacy on the international stage, and it would be very difficult for Putin's government to keep the support of the Russian population.

This is why Russian state media have been [accusing the Ukrainian government of genocide](https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2022-02-17/russia-ukraine-disinformation-campaign), and this is why the US are trying to counter this narrative [by exposing its fabrication](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/feb/03/ukraine-russia-fake-attack-video-us-claims). Preemptively exposing the Russian disinformation strategy undermines the efforts of Russian propaganda. The Russian government needs to disseminate quickly and broadly some very shocking news which justifies the invasion. In general, even if the disinformation is debunked eventually, it's always too little too late. But this strategy is much less effective if the disinformation is "defused" in advance by the US and their allies, since the shock effect doesn't work and people are much more suspicious. The constant reminder by the US that Russia has its army ready to strike also contributes to this purpose, since it implies that any "shocking event" triggering the war probably did not happen now by chance.

Comment: Comments deleted - if you’d like to write your own answer to this question, please do so in the answer box.

Comment: "lose its legitimacy on the international stage" - Russia still has legitimacy left to lose?

Comment: @Vikki pretty much yes. Russia has its rather strong fan-club of people leaning far-left (traditionally), people leaning far-right (a recent development), people simply ill-informed (an impressive majority everywhere even if not all of them Russian fans), politicians/leaders of various sorts, etc, etc... Russia did their homework in Georgia in 2008 and got a lot of international support back then.

Comment: @fraxinus I think not many leftists have been fans of Russia since three decades ago.

Comment: @Vikki: I think in this case, Erwan is talking about legitimacy as a nation that other countries can engage in diplomacy / trade agreements with (e.g. oil and gas deals), not as a democracy or that its public claims about itself are realistic.

Comment: @Jasmijn wrong, at least here (Bulgaria). 30 years are almost enough for a lot of people to change their views.

Comment: Might it be simply that the US thinks it matters enough to keep commenting?

Comment: it's a month later, Russia has invaded Ukraine, and this answer is reasonably correct.

Answer (score 35):

I mostly agree with [Ted](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/70825/why-does-the-us-keep-announcing-what-they-think-russia-is-going-to-do-in-ukraine/70839#70839) and [Erwan](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/70825/why-does-the-us-keep-announcing-what-they-think-russia-is-going-to-do-in-ukraine/70835#70835), but I would put it slightly differently. Say the US claims/warns/predicts that Russia will invade Ukraine on February 16th, as they [did](https://www.politico.com/newsletters/national-security-daily/2022/02/11/putin-could-attack-ukraine-on-feb-16-biden-told-allies-00008344). Then there are three possible scenarios:

- Russia **does** invade. It takes more reputation damage than it would do without the warning, as outlined by the other answers. This reputation damage translates into a higher Western unity for sanctions.
- Russia **never planned** to invade. Russian reputation is tarnished in the eye of those who incorrectly think it was merely deterred from the invasion, and the US reputation is tarnished in the eye of those who consider the US a bully and self-serving liar.
- Russia is deterred from a **planned** invasion by the prospect for higher reputation damage (as per bullet point 1). Again, Russian reputation is tarnished in the eye of those who correctly think it was merely deterred from the invasion, and the US reputation is tarnished in the eye of those who consider the US a bully.

Obviously the US decided that the possible reputation loss from being alarmist outweighs the damage of an invasion to the international system, and so takes steps to make the invasion less likely. Think of it as an **insurance premium**. *On average*, insurance costs more than the damage it covers. When you take insurance for something, you are *certain* to pay the premium, but the impact of a low-probability, high-damage event is reduced.

Comment: These are interesting points, but I fail to understand how the US would appear as a bully or would stand to suffer significant loss of reputation. Do you have citations or further evidence to suggest this? As I see it, America's reputational gamble will be staked on the effectiveness of any sanctions that may be imposed, not on whether it displays clairvoyance regarding Russia's intent to invade.

Comment: @Beau, bullet points two and three assume *no* invasion and hence *no* sanctions. They differ in Russia's secret plans, not any observable behaviour. I would call the Chinese reaction to Russian complaints an example of the US reputation loss.

Comment: @Beau Consider klm123's answer. That viewpoint is not very rare globally, even though it is not common in western countries.

Comment: @o.m.: Personally, I am somewhat skeptical that the US seriously cares about China's opinion one way or the other, unless China pairs that opinion with some sort of concrete action.

Comment: @Kevin, part of the US might not care, but that was just one example. The US wants to be liked, like most other countries.

Comment: There's talk around here (in Western Europe) about whether the US is trying to prevent a war or trying to goad Russia into one. If this answer is correct, then there's clearly some reputation damage being done to the US by taking this path to avoid a war.

Comment: Another reputational cost for the US, in case there is no invasion, is getting perceived as “the boy who cried wolf”.  (I’m not saying they *are* crying wolf, even if no invasion comes — it’s certainly plausible that this US strategy may deter an invasion that otherwise would have happened — but at least some are likely to read it that way.)

Comment: Interesting points, and I appreciate all of the opinions. I have a hard time thinking of it as as boy-who-cried-wolf scenario since Putin has very publicly displayed an unwavering interest in military conquest of Ukraine, and also has 100k soldiers stationed just outside the borders. I would say the wolves are circling in plain view.  Also, to my thinking, there is a difference between simply being further disliked by nations and individuals who already dislike the US, and actually *losing face* amongst peer nations.

Answer (score 13):

Because it's very difficult to do a surprise attack, when someone has just announced what your surprise attack is going to be.

It's like the rabbit that spots a fox across a field.  It sits bolt upright, looking straight at the fox.  At that point, the fox knows it isn't going to succeed in a surprise attack on the rabbit.

Comment: In my personal experience, neither the fox nor the rabbit will directly look at the other in such situations.

Comment: @M.Stern Partly because rabbits see most clearly to the sides, not straight ahead like humans.

Comment: Maybe gophers is a better example?

Comment: @M.Stern Maybe.  The thing about rabbits and foxes may be apocryphal.

Comment: How does this answer the question? In this metaphor, Ukraine is the rabbit and Russia is the fox, but who's the USA? OP is already aware that the rabbit knowing about the fox is beneficial, but asked, "Wouldn't it be better to just tell the Ukrainian government what you know and let them decide how to handle the public relations in the matter?"

Comment: After the events of 2014, a new invasion can hardly be a surprise for either Ukraine or the rest of the world. I'm pretty sure the US is trying to make it clear that Russia was preparing the invasion **before** whatever excuse Putin finds to justify it, not to warn an unsuspecting rabbit about the fox.

Comment: But if the US informed the Ukranian government of its suspicions instead of announcing them publicly (as the question suggests) then the element of surprise would still be lost. This therefore doesn't answer the question, which is why *announce* rather than merely inform those who need to know?

Comment: @JBentley the advantage of announcing it publicly is that not only do the Ukrainians get to see the US assessment of what Russia is doing, but the Russians now know that Ukraine knows.

Comment: @SimonB That can be acheived by informing Russia privately. You've still not provided a reason for the *public* announcement. See e.g. [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/70835/6764) which specifically targets the public announcement aspect.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why the US makes PUBLIC announcements. It would serve the same purpose of simply inform their allies and the Ukraine government.

Comment: @Tom Well, Russia invaded Ukraine anyway, and this information has helped turn the general worldwide public opinion against Russia.

Answer (score 12):

That's not what the US is doing.  Various US officials have announced what, in the estimate of the known sources, ***is likely to happen if nothing changes.***

This is done in order to allow the affected parties to prepare for the dangerous eventualities and for the effecting parties to be aware that their actions are not going unnoticed.

Because of these announcements some will mitigate risks and some will course correct in the directions which have less harmful outcomes.

This may create the impression that the original "predictions" were wrong.  But they were no more wrong than a passenger yelling "watch out" at a driver of his car, who doesn't see that he is about to run over a pedestrian.  The driver has an opportunity to course correct and avoid a disaster.

Answer (score 5):

Such announcements are actually good publicity: the US is showing to everyone that they are involved in an international crisis and are trying to resolve it peacefully. I think it's nothing like [*insurance premium*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/70840/6909) - looking at past deeds of Putin in Georgia and Ukraine one can hardly label the US to be "the boy who cried wolf", invasion warnings are justified even if there's no invasion in the end.

In fact, the US gets most reputational gains if the invasion doesn't happen: **Biden gets to say he managed to keep Putin in check while he was in the White House**. If the invasion does happen, the US will have to either confront Russia, or get the blame for not getting involved. I understand Ukrainian politicians are trying to show their loyalty to the US and expecting some sort of protection in return, and it's in the US' best interest that this protection doesn't involve actual warfare with casualties.

Comment: This would mean the USA has to gain from this announcement if Russia doesn't invade and has to lose if it invades (compared to the case they haven't made this announcement)... so this would allege that the USA doesn't find the invasion likely, or they wouldn't have made the announcement.

Comment: @vsz I wouldn't say that the US loses if Russia invades Ukraine. It's just the less desirable  outcome that will force them to make a hard choice between getting involved in a conflict, and ignoring Ukraine in their hour of need. Frankly, an invasion would be catastrophic for both Russia and Ukraine, which is why I'm [convinced](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/70771/6909) it won't happen.

Comment: Publicity, kind of: It's better to announce what they think will happen ahead of time, rather than saying "we had no idea" after it had happened.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely certain, but I could think of a few reasons.

For one, likely generally transparency, especially with the American people. This is particularly important, should military action be necessary and/or taken. This transparency aids in keeping informed.

The other is to likely raise attention and give a platform in the international community to help deter Russia from taking those actions and aid in a strong negative sentiment towards Russia taking those actions.

I would imagine if they're doing it there is generally a good reason, or they at least have a good reason in mind. There is likely much more intelligence we are not aware of (naturally) and I would assume that is being shared privately with the necessary channels.

Answer (score 4):

> ...why is the US specifically pumping out all these statements and claims about Russia/Ukraine in the first place?

Concentrating on that part only and given that the US predictions were quite accurate all the time, I guess that one factor was that the US was quite sure about what happened there. Given their intelligence information about the troops, positions and maybe even attack plans, they might have been almost sure that Russia seriously was preparing for attacking Ukraine.

And if you are so sure, why not make that knowledge public. The US seems to have gained a lot of credibility by their open communication during that period, even though it didn't change anything else.

Example:

On [18th of February the US president](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/biden-convinced-putin-made-decision-invade-ukraine-crisis/story?id=82983667) said that "We have reason to believe the Russian forces are planning and intend to attack Ukraine in the coming week, the coming days," and "We believe that they will target Ukraine's capital Kyiv — a city of 2.8 million innocent people." which is as far as I can see 100% accurate. Probably the intelligence information was good enough to deduct that with certainty.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple: There is just one thing you need to know - Russia and USA has been at opposition for many years.

One can hypothesize a lot about all possible goals and reasons USA and Russia have, just like what exactly made Ukraine to be at the situation it is right now. But regardless of all these reasons and hypotheses - destroying public image of Russia is proficient for USA.
The situation in Ukraine comes here as a convenient instrument.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

It's propaganda as a preparation for actual war.

As such, it is not unlike the repetitive claims of presence of WMDs in Iraq, while Iraq was screaming to anyone who would listen to come and see for themselves,... which nobody did or got loud enough about.

Except for less than a decade of its existence, the United States has been in a continuous state of war with some nation or another. Practice makes perfect, as the saying goes. What actually is or is not happening in Ukraine, or what Russia is doing, is irrelevant.

The sole purpose of these allegations is to justify oncoming actions of the US itself. They are a means to an end and in themselves neither particularly diplomatic nor solution oriented.

Comment: I've gotten the impression that the US (where I live) has learned from that disaster in the lead up to the Iraq invasion.  Specifically, I *think* the US is disclosing to allies actual conversations/messages backing up public claims.

Comment: Also, that last bit about "sole purpose" seems a bit far fetched, considering actual shelling by Russians going on right now.

Comment: @donjuedo If you dig into US warfare history, you will find a surprisingly consequent recurrence of tactics. BSing the US population into believing Saddam had WMDs is one of the most peaceful ways the US ever initiated a war. Events like Pearl Harbor and 9/11 serve the same purpose, but at a way higher price. To an understanding person, the meaning of these public messages is, things are going to go sideways. There is not going to be no war in Ukraine. Regardless how much I would pray to God I'm wrong in that, this is what I'm reading.

Comment: @donjuedo Answering your second comment: Putin is not very susceptible to bluff, or threats for that matter. "Sole Purpose" is because that is the only result it realistically can be expected to actually have. Not because I can't fantasize up any other reason. If things aren't what they seem, there is still some what is real to be found in what seems, just because what seems is there.

Comment: @Berend are you saying that the US government did Pearl Harbour and 9/11??

Comment: @coagmano In this respect "did" is a very big word. What I can say with some certainty is, that every major endeavor of US military was preceded by some catalyzing event. The trick in successfully going to war is not in having the necessary military power to start it, but much more in having the necessary population support to sustain it.  Both Pearl harbor and 9/11 are such events and both are to this day highly questioned. WMDs and Tonkin bay are even officially acknowledged as fictional.  What the "truth" is, is not relevant. It's a very efficient strategy.

Comment: May I ask which country do you think the US is going to attack? Russia? Ukraine?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev It doesn't necessarily precede an attack, but the US hasn't exactly  been hiding the fact that they prefer to use central and west Europe as a battle ground for any final confrontation between the remaining powers. They have successfully avoided a direct clash so far, mainly by taking the fight to some disputed back yard or another. The US has up to now never attacked a nuclear capable nation and odds are it never will. However, should the US get involved militarily in the Ukraine conflict, they're not gonna send any helmets. I can promise you that.

Comment: @Berend There is a far cry difference between manufacturing a catalyst for war and using an existing catalyst. Your answer, and subsequent comments imply the US manufactured reasons to be in a perpetual state of war and is inciting the current crisis to create more war.

Comment: @DavidS That's not at all the way I see it. I don't include judgement. It's all just observation. There would never be any one person to judge, but rather a process and as far as I can see, there is not much point in judging a process. Manufacturing a catalyst as in a personal goal is almost impossible to achieve. Yet catalysts have been manufactured in the past and will be in the future.. The answer does not clear the question entirely, but points out it does serve a US foreign policy purpose.which isn't  peaceful by nature. .The US evidently believes in war as a useful instrument.

Comment: @DavidS I guess your thoughts about it come from not being familiar with how little difference there actually is between manufacturing a catalyst for war and using an existing one. Both are efforts in the same direction and can't exist without each other. There is always intend involved, as well as circumstance.. It is never entirely made up and there is no such thing as absolute coincidence.

Comment: @Berend "I don't include judgement." and "The sole purpose of these allegations is to justify oncoming actions of the US itself." are not in agreement. The declarative statement of sole purpose requires prior judgement of opinion without any sources or citations for context. Also, there are massive differences between the manufacture of a catalyst and using one. From very narrow perspectives I would agree with you. But in the broad sense, it matters. If not, this question wouldn't have been asked. The US is only beating this drum because Russia was caught manufacturing pretext previously.

Comment: @Berend You're ignoring complexities here to draw the picture you want. What Russia is doing is very relevant, just like what Japan was doing at Pearl Harbor was very relevant. The US actions are explicitly in response to Russian actions (another country that's almost always been at war), and whatever the US goals are, their actions are taken in a careful dance with Russia and the other players in this drama.

Comment: @DavidS We appear to be looking from different angles. I wouldn't mind continuing discussing this, but that is not the purpose of this place. I tried to answer a question as best as I know how. That it provokes certain emotional responses is inherent to the subject. People use different glasses looking for different things for different purposes. If my answer doesn't make you any wiser, feel free to ignore it. I don't mind being (called) wrong.

Comment: @prosfilaes Farmers don't grow crops. They wouldn't know how. They merely allow crops to grow themselves. That doesn't mean farmers don't have a conclusive influence on the outcome. I analyze and compare. Relevance is relative. The question is about a relation. Many are suggested. I exclude and see what is left. It is not an invalid way of looking at things. It's just different.

Comment: @prosfilaes To be complete: You are right, I am ignoring complexities and for good reason. As the saying goes, it ain't the complexities that make the clock tick. To find out what does make the clock tick, I selectively ignore or reject complexities. The selection is in the other answers. The rejection is through loss of relevance by reduction of relation. It's processing knowledge of others, rather than trying to understand anything myself..

Answer (score 2):

This is called declarative strategy.

Did you know the Russians sent bataillons and anti aircraft missile batteries to repel the Ukrainian army from the cities of Lougansk and Donetsk? That this caused thousands of deaths in the Ukrainian army? This happened in 2014.

Today, Russia seems close to at least a similar intervention, at worse (from the Ukrainian point of view) an all-out invasion. The USA need to acknowledge the situation publicly, in front of everyone, in order to:

- Legitimaze their intervention if they need to intervene
- Tell the Russians they are aware of their possible invasion and they won't let them do their things as in 2014

Comment: On the other hand, if the US didn't want Russia to do their things in 2014, they would have stopped them back then.

Comment: @Andyc In 2014 the Russians played it hidden, so the USA were unable to pressure plublicly (it would have been of no effect because the Russians were denying). Today, by saying "the russians will attack" you prepare the public pressions

Comment: Exactly: in 2014 Russian troops were spotted only *after* the conflict started. This time, the US is telling everyone the troops were deployed *before* any incident that could justify their presence.

Answer (score -5):

American government is trying to stop the war that the Russian regime is planning in Ukraine.

The US population and political campaign donors do not need a war. A war would negatively impact the financial markets, as evidenced by the drops in major stock market indices immediately after the tensions and uncertainty associated with the conflict increased. A war in Europe would be a humanitarian catastrophe (refugees, etc) for Europe and will adversely affect the markets and drive up inflation. With an exception of the weapons manufacturers, trade would be negatively affected. Assuming that political corruption depends linearly on the market cap of the entities that carry out the corruption, we can rule out the major political donors of the US as the factor that increases the likelihood of war.

By announcing the Russian FSB military plans in real time, by making the intel public, the US is depriving Russia of the critical element of surprise. By laying bare the plans of false flag attacks in front of the entire world, the value of such staged attacks is reduced. The only remaining value is to preach to the converted, that is, to that part of the media audience that has already accepted that Ukraine is the aggressor no matter what evidence is presented to the contrary. On the other hand, roughly half of Russians believe that the West and Ukraine are the aggressors in the conflict, which is about 10-fold higher that those that believe that Russia is the aggressor. So announcing the plans of the FSB military arm is definitely not a panacea for this conflict.

If Gleiwitz was announced similarly, maybe WWII would have been delayed. Same goes for WWIII.

**REFERENCES:**

> Announcing new sanctions on Thursday, President Joe Biden cited his administration’s moves to warn of what it knew of Putin’s intentions.
>
> “We shared declassified evidence about Russia’s plans and false pretext so that there could be no confusion or cover-up about what Putin’s doing,” he said. “Putin is the aggressor. Putin chose this war. And now he and his country will bear the consequences.”
>
> Sen. Mark Warner, a Virginia Democrat who chairs the Senate Intelligence Committee, noted several results of the public campaign: weakening any potential move by Putin to create a “false-flag” operation to justify war, undercutting any potential coup in Kyiv that might have appeared to be led by Ukrainians, and unifying allies who quickly denounced Putin’s aggression this week and backed tough sanctions.
>
> “The intelligence community usually doesn’t like to share information; they want to hold it close,” Warner said in an interview. “What they’ve done is push the Russian timeline back. They’ve also, I think, allowed us to build this coalition that is virtually unprecedented.”
>
> Ohio Rep. Mike Turner, the top Republican on the House Intelligence Committee, said the Biden administration’s declassifying of information was “incredibly important.”
>
> “This has both impacted the international community’s view of Putin and has slowed his actions,” Turner said. “The goal in releasing intelligence is to permit Ukraine to plan, and any delay in Putin’s actions helped Ukraine in the planning to defend itself.”

*U.S. intel accurately predicted Russia’s invasion plans. Did it matter? February 25, 2022: https://www.cnbc.com/2022/02/25/us-intel-predicted-russias-invasion-plans-did-it-matter.html*

Comment: The US can deprive Russia of the element of surprise by (privately) informing Ukraine of its suspicions (as suggested by the question). This doesn't answer the question of why to make the announcement public vs private. The real reason is likely about public perception. See e.g. [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/70835/6764).

Comment: @JBentley It is best to let this thug know that we know that he is a thug. My experience of dealing with Putin’s kind is that they shy away from transparency. Bullies are afraid of being exposed. :)

Comment: Be that as it may (or may not), that isn't what your answer says. Your answer is based on depriving Russia of the element of surprise. If instead your point is that exposing Putin's plan publicly has some benefit which exposing it privately does not, then you should edit that into your answer. As it currently stands, it doesn't address the question asked.

Comment: "Let me know if I need to explain why that it true." Given the way they are exploiting the tension you definitely need to explain that assertion.

Comment: @JBentley Thank you for the feedback, edited the answer.

Comment: @FluidCode Thank you for the feedback, edited the answer.

Comment: @TimurShtatland Trouble is that the evidence you put is based on assumption that are not very credible. The American government works for the sake of the financial elites that thrives by anticipating and exploiting ups and downs in the market and in the world economy. As for the refugess they couldn't care less.